# How to scale instantiated prefab objects in unity to fit different screen sizes

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen, scale, prefab

Hey i am wondering if there is a way in unity for you to scale prefab objects that is instantiated to be able to fit different screen sizes in unity so that no matter the device your game is downloaded on, the prefab too would scale.

Comment: Doesn't makes sense, rather, bring your camera closer according whatever metrics.

Comment: @aybe how do i do that? Is there a script i can use?

Comment: @Jerry Just add a camera as a child to the prefab for each prefab and set one active and the rest inactive until needed and move the camera.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve but, myself I would first look at fitting these on screen using camera frustum to have an equal result on each screen size. From there, depending whatever, you may eventually move the camera closer or away but again, it hardly makes sense; why would you want a different result according different screen size?